# What is the fastest way to get back to previous active tab in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I use **vimium** in chrome,and every time I open a new tab and tend to go back to previous tab,I have to use my mouse or touch pad,Is there any trick to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Use Chrome Vimium which provides a lot of shortcuts

- ^ Go to previously-visited tab
- T search through your open tabs
- (number+)d(u) half page down(up)

Check more [Chrome Vimium Tips, Tricks](https://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2019/04/awesome-tips-about-chrome-vimium.html)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a new built-in update called Search Tabs.

Feature includes:

- search tabs by title
- shows recently opened tabs

Shortcut key is set by default to **CTRL + SHIFT + A**

Comment: In what way is this superior to previous answers, or is it simply another method?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is but it's built-in, so no need for an extension. It's very useful for me since I open a lot of pages. I think it's better since you can search for a tab by title or just press enter to go to recent opened tab.

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `Ctrl+Shift+TAB`. This will go backwards. If you want to go forward you can do this without shift.

**Edit:** That is a great resource on hotkeys:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Comment: [0][1*][2][3][new tab],I was in tab [1] ,and I open [new tab] in [1],and now I'm in [new tab] and I want to back to [1]

Comment: You can't really go to previously selected tab. You can only go there using `Ctrl+Number`, but you have to know which tab it is

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to switch tabs using keyboard shortcuts like:

To switch to the next tab:
Ctrl+Tab or Ctrl+PgDown

To switch to the previous tab:
Ctrl+Shift+Tab or Ctrl+PgUp

To switch to a specific tab:
Ctrl+1 to Ctrl+8

To switch to the last tab:
Ctrl+9

Source: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/af0CrX_48pk

Answer (score 0):

QuicKey – The quick tab switcher
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg/related

Does the job beautifully.

Answer (score -3):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + [Tab index] that starts from 1, In your case: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>